# Multiply CDF by constant, what is the expected value of this "new" CDF?

Tags: expected-value, cumulative-distribution-function

Specifically, I want to multiply $F_X(x)$ by $E(X)$, so I have

$$
??? = E(X)\cdot F_X(x) = \int^b_a xf_X(x)dx\cdot \int^b_a f_X(x)dx \overset{?}{=}\int^b_ax\Big(f_X(x)\Big)^2dx
$$

Is there a way to write $???$ in terms of $E(X)$, i.e. simplify this? It's clearly not $E(X^2)$ nor $\Big(E(X)\Big)^2$? Is it $E\big[Xf_X(x)\big]$?

Comment: You should invest some time and effort in basic calculus as the product of integrals _is not_ the integral of the product in most cases...

Comment: I agree that would be useful. However, at this point I do not have any ambitions of becoming a master of calculus and would therefore just want an answer to my question.

Comment: What I meant by my comment is that a minimum background is necessary to handle the question.

Comment: I understand that. However I am only interested in the final answer. I don't think I need any calculus to copy paste.

Answer (score 1):

Since $E[X]$ is a constant, you can write it as

$E[X] F_X(x) =\int_{-\infty}^x E[X] f_X(t)dt$.

In responde to your edit:

No, since $E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x f_X(x)dx$ you should see that you cannot mix the two integrals.

Comment: So my calculations above are incorrect since, as Xi'an said, the product of integrals is not the integral of the product? In this particular case, that is.

Comment: Yes, user Xi'an is right. I edited my answer in response of your edit.

Comment: I understand. However, if the pdf is only defined on [a, b], then isn't the expected value also integrated over that interval? Rather than from -infinity to infinity. I am assuming you are referring to an issue with the intervals.

Comment: Hmm I think I see your point. $F_X(x)$ is integrated over $[-\inf, x]$, not over $[a, b]$.

Comment: In other words, the thing is that $F_X(x)$ is a function of $x$, while $E[X]$ is not, it is a constant.

Comment: Take a distribution of a continuous variable (e.g. Beta distribution) and look at the two quantities, it will be more clear I hope.